# Function doesn't count the amount of elements correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey, userscripts

I use [`waitForKeyElements`](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891) function by [Brock Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331508/brock-adams) to create the checkboxes after the links on the https://www.google.com/.

For some reason, the function works incorrectly. Instead of placing the single checkbox after each link, it counts all the links, and then add the corresponding amount of checkboxes after each of them.

What could be the error?

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @grant   none
// @match   https://*.google.*/
// @name    Google.com
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
// @require https://gist.githubusercontent.com/BrockA/2625891/raw/9c97aa67ff9c5d56be34a55ad6c18a314e5eb548/waitForKeyElements.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    function test() {
        var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'checkbox';
            links[i].parentElement.appendChild(input);
        }
    }

    //waitForKeyElements('a', test); // works incorrectly. The third parameter
        // doesn't help.
    //setTimeout(test(), 3000); // works OK
})();
```

The function itself:

```js
/*--- waitForKeyElements():  A utility function, for Greasemonkey scripts,
    that detects and handles AJAXed content.

    Usage example:

        waitForKeyElements (
            "div.comments"
            , commentCallbackFunction
        );

        //--- Page-specific function to do what we want when the node is found.
        function commentCallbackFunction (jNode) {
            jNode.text ("This comment changed by waitForKeyElements().");
        }

    IMPORTANT: This function requires your script to have loaded jQuery.
*/
function waitForKeyElements (
    selectorTxt,    /* Required: The jQuery selector string that
                        specifies the desired element(s).
                    */
    actionFunction, /* Required: The code to run when elements are
                        found. It is passed a jNode to the matched
                        element.
                    */
    bWaitOnce,      /* Optional: If false, will continue to scan for
                        new elements even after the first match is
                        found.
                    */
    iframeSelector  /* Optional: If set, identifies the iframe to
                        search.
                    */
) {
    var targetNodes, btargetsFound;

    if (typeof iframeSelector == "undefined")
        targetNodes     = $(selectorTxt);
    else
        targetNodes     = $(iframeSelector).contents ()
                                           .find (selectorTxt);

    if (targetNodes  &&  targetNodes.length > 0) {
        btargetsFound   = true;
        /*--- Found target node(s).  Go through each and act if they
            are new.
        */
        targetNodes.each ( function () {
            var jThis        = $(this);
            var alreadyFound = jThis.data ('alreadyFound')  ||  false;

            if (!alreadyFound) {
                //--- Call the payload function.
                var cancelFound     = actionFunction (jThis);
                if (cancelFound)
                    btargetsFound   = false;
                else
                    jThis.data ('alreadyFound', true);
            }
        } );
    }
    else {
        btargetsFound   = false;
    }

    //--- Get the timer-control variable for this selector.
    var controlObj      = waitForKeyElements.controlObj  ||  {};
    var controlKey      = selectorTxt.replace (/[^\w]/g, "_");
    var timeControl     = controlObj [controlKey];

    //--- Now set or clear the timer as appropriate.
    if (btargetsFound  &&  bWaitOnce  &&  timeControl) {
        //--- The only condition where we need to clear the timer.
        clearInterval (timeControl);
        delete controlObj [controlKey]
    }
    else {
        //--- Set a timer, if needed.
        if ( ! timeControl) {
            timeControl = setInterval ( function () {
                    waitForKeyElements (    selectorTxt,
                                            actionFunction,
                                            bWaitOnce,
                                            iframeSelector
                                        );
                },
                300
            );
            controlObj [controlKey] = timeControl;
        }
    }
    waitForKeyElements.controlObj   = controlObj;
}
```

Comment: remove the `loop`

Comment: Can you provide an example so it could be reproduced?

Comment: @DiogoPeres I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Simply install it as userscript, uncomment `waitForKeyElements` line in the bottom, and then visit google.com page. You will see a lot of checkboxes here and there. Also, see the comments under David's answer to better understand the overall picture.

Comment: @johnc.j. sorry, my fault, I didn't understood you had to visit google.com page.

Comment: Do not add the solution to the question. If you've answered your own question, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't provide your use case of `waitForKeyElements`, but if I understand correctly, you pass the `test` function to it. If that's the case - no wonder it appends X checkboxes to every link on the page. Look closely:
- Your function, upon being called, searches for all the links in the page and add a checkbox next to it
- `waitForKeyElements` calls that function **for every element it finds** based on the selector provided.
So, basically, if the page has 50 links, if will append one checkbox after every link 50 times.

The solution is to not loop over in your function, but add a checkbox only once, to the argument provided:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function test(element) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'checkbox';
        element.parent().append(input);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Hi, David. It was my fault that I provided slightly simplified use case. Actually, when I click the checkbox, the corresponding link should became visited. Generally, this idea works. The only problem that I can't understand how to make it work with your fix. Here is the updated code, without your changes: https://pastebin.com/raw/EMFjbiKJ

Comment: Ok, but that really changes nothing, the only change you want to make is to make sure `test` function accepts a single argument (a jQuery element) and instead of iterating over a loop, simply add a checkbox (with event listener) to this element. By the way, I've noticed that you use vanilla js DOM manipulation; consider using jQuery, because the function that you use (`waitForKeyElements`) already does, so it would simplify things I think.

Comment: Well, the checkboxes are shown properly. But now, when I click them, the links doesn't became visited: https://pastebin.com/raw/xF1udFAA.

Comment: In my original code the checkboxes works. With the last version I posted, they stopped to work. Do you know how to make them work (again) and, at the same time, to avoid the excessive ones?

Comment: I don't know what's the case here, but probably something's wrong with the event listener callback; anyway, it's kind of beyond the scope of this question, so maybe you should try adding another, or just debug the callback on yourself. Maybe try manipulating this element only with jQuery, I don't know.

Comment: I cannot agree that "it's kind of beyond the scope of this question". Technically, the fix you provided breaks the existing way the code worked. Now I edited the question and now it mentions that checkboxes must work, not just exist.